# How to check order in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have list like `['one', 'two', 'finish', 'one', 'two', 'two']`:

If 'two' comes before 'finish' and then after finish I need to return `checkFlag = true`

I tried with below code.

```js
const empList = ['one', 'two', 'finish', 'one', 'two', 'two'];

const map = new Map(empList.map((emp, index) => [emp, index]));

const checkFlag = map.get('two') < map.get('finish');
console.log(checkFlag);
```

Comment: `checkFlag = empList.indexOf('two') < empList.indexOf('finish')`

Comment: where is the type script :)

Answer (score 3):

```js
const empList = ['one', 'two', 'finish', 'one', 'two', 'two'];
const firstPoint = empList.indexOf('two');
const finishIndex = empList.indexOf('finish');
const lastPoint = empList.lastIndexOf('two');

console.log(firstPoint < finishIndex && finishIndex < lastPoint)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a way to do this in just one iteration of that array, which would be something like this:

```js
const empList = ['one', 'two', 'finish', 'one', 'two', 'two'];
var checkFlag = false
const relevant = []
for (const element of empList){
  if(element === "two"){
    relevant.push(true)
  } else if(element === "finish"){
    relevant.push(false)
  }
}

if(
  relevant[0] 
  && relevant[relevant.length - 1] 
  && relevant.length >= 3
){
  checkFlag = true
}

console.log(checkFlag)
```

Comment: What about the second part? "'two' comes before 'finish' and **then after finish**"

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I am not following, I thought it meant: "After position is compared, I need to return checkFlag = true." Did I misunderstand it?

Comment: "and then after finish" - need to check `two` elem after `finish`

Comment: Oh I see so... `two`...`finish`...`two` => `checkFlag=true`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const empList = ['one', 'two', 'finish', 'one', 'two', 'two'];

const finish = empList.indexOf('finish');

const checkFlag = empList.indexOf('two') < finish && empList.lastIndexOf('two') > finish;
console.log(checkFlag);
```